# Filtering each by category in model - ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

According to title - how I can make that happend?

So I have `models/project`

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    image: DS.attr('string'),

    category: DS.attr('string')  
});
```

And I want to filter items by category string in `projects/index.hbs`

```
{{#each project in model}}
    <h3>{{project.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{project.description}}</p>
{{/each}}

...

{{#each project in model}}
    <h3>{{project.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{project.description}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

For example some projects have category **web** and the others have **logo**

In first `{{#each}}` loop I wanna display **web** category and **logo** in the second.

Should I do that by controller? or in the route? PS. What to do to make it appear as default, not by clicking to make `action: sortBy` etc. I really tried find the answer by myself but nothing yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `computed property` to your controller which filters your projects by category.

```
  webCategoryProjects: function() {
    return this.get('model').filterBy('category', 'web');
  }.property('model.@each.category'),

  logoCategoryProjects: function() {
    return this.get('model').filterBy('category', 'logo');
  }.property('model.@each.category'),

{{#each project in webCategoryProjects}}
    <h3>{{project.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{project.description}}</p>
{{/each}}

...

{{#each project in logoCategoryProjects}}
    <h3>{{project.title}}</h3>
    <p>{{project.description}}</p>
{{/each}}
```